# R dataframe to JSON array of objects

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have an R dataframe in the following format

```
id  code  value
1   A      3
2   B      5 
3   C      9
```

using:

```
  toJSON(df)
  returns:
  [{id:1,code:A,value:3},...]
```

My desired output is:

```
[{1,A,3},{2,B,5}..]
```

using

```
 df <- unname(df)
 returns an array of arrays, [[..],[..],...]]
```

I am using the package jsonlite

Comment: `[{1,A,3},{2,B,5}]` is not a valid JSON.

Comment: If you are looking for the `[{1,A,3},{2,B,5}..]` for that you need to have a key-value format as it is a JSON format. Something like `[{id:1,code:A,value:3}]`

Comment: Thanks. I will alter my code accordingly. I wanted without column names, but I think key-value format will be applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nicola said, what you've requested (`[{1,A,3},{2,B,5},...]`) is not valid JSON. I believe the closest you can get (without the names) is this:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='id  code  value
1   A      3
2   B      5 
3   C      9')
library(jsonlite)

toJSON(lapply(seq.int(nrow(df)), function(i) unname(lapply(df, `[[`, i))),
       auto_unbox=TRUE)
# [[1,"A",3],[2,"B",5],[3,"C",9]]
```

Normally, `jsonlite` likes to keep scalars as vectors-of-one, so if you remove the `auto_unbox=TRUE` component, you'll get:

```
toJSON(lapply(seq.int(nrow(df)), function(i) unname(lapply(df, `[[`, i))))
# [[[1],["A"],[3]],[[2],["B"],[5]],[[3],["C"],[9]]]
```

which might be functionally the same depending on how you are consuming this data. (I agree that the unboxed implementation is much easier for a human to read.)

Both methods preserve the type (number, string) of the columns' values.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I wanted it without column names, so this will work. Will read more on key-value format.